# C++ string parser

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I'm wondering how to implement a string parser able to parse variables being passed in a string, similar to the Python logger.

```
int number{1};
string word{"world"};
log.info("Hello {word}. Message number {number}.");
```

Comment: There was another similar question just a few days ago by another python programmer. C++ doesn't provide a direct companion to python logger. You can easily write one by passing a reference to your `std::string` and your `int` as parameters to a function.

Comment: This is likely not possible (at least not easily) in C++. C++ is a compiled language, and variable names don't exist at runtime. You would need to somehow parse the string at compile-time and replace the variable names in the string with some sort of reference to the variable. If you don't need the variable names to be embedded in the string, then you can write a function that takes the value of the variable separately.

Comment: You can take a look at how [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) does it.

Comment: @IanGralinski fmt passes the variables as arguments.

Comment: That's a hard requirement in C++ until reflection is implemented, and even then that will always be a more efficient way than banging around in the symbol table looking for values.

Comment: Please see [fmt library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) source code.

Comment: This is now in the new `C++20` standard.